# Difference between Zepto and jQuery

Tags: jquery, zepto

I read that Zepto.js has almost the same functions as jQuery but it's much smaller and faster than the latter.
So why should I prefer jQuery? What are the differences between Zepto and jQuery?

The browser compatibility is almost the same.

Comment: I've read documantation and that why i asked this question

Answer (score 2):

Because jQuery also suports old browsers (of example ie9). at least jquery v1 does v2 doesn't support ie8 anymore

**EDIT**

I read that not all jquery plugins are supported by zepto and that the laod time me be faster but the preformance of zepto once loaded are not as good as jQuery

Comment: and this is only difference between them?

Comment: is there any situation when i should prefer using zepto over jquery?
and does it worth learning?

Comment: The file size difference is so minimal i dont think that makes a loth of difference. maybe when it are just mobile users with slow internet but look at jQuery 2 that is also smaller because they removed the older browser support. but still supports IE 9  but not Ie < 9 and like they say "If you use jQuery, you already know how to use Zepto." so there is not need to learn anything new to use it